# Bash console tab-completion in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tabs, console, tab-completion

I used to develop in RedHat and never had the following problem until I switched to Ubuntu:

Whenever I use tab-completion (which is ALL the time) I noticed that depending on what command I am about to execute the behavior differs. For example:

vim fold (<kbd>tab</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>) will show me the contents of that folder:

```
vim folder/
file1 file2 file3 etc
```

If I happen to change the command to 'ls' then behavior changes:

ls fold (<kbd>tab</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>) -> "ls folder "

Notice the " " space at end of folder - I can't look inside folder with <kbd>tab</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, I have to backspace and add '/', which is MOST rage inducing. Where can I go to modify this functionality, or disable completely so it is consistent all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41707/bash-auto-completion-with-added-spaces-why-and-how-to-fix), the answer is to edit the `/etc/bash_completion` file and somewhere around line 1587 change the keyword `default` to `filenames`.

I have not verified. Also, I am running 12.04 LTS and I don't seem to have this problem.